# Excel VBA- Code suddenly get a runtime error 91 (AutoFilter)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that will search and copy from one sheet to another by using autofiler. I included my code below. My problem here is that, earlier (2 weeks ago), the code worked just fine as intended, I've tested the code so many time and there is no error. Suddenly, there is runtime error 91 when I run the code, and the error seems to be with this line:

```
.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B10")
```

I've tried the `.AutoFilter=False`, error handling and also worksheet activate. But I still get the same runtime error. Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with my code? any helps are much appreciated.

```
Sub search()
    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Master")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Fruit")
    'Worksheets("Fruit").Activate

    With ws1
        '.AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("B7").AutoFilter
        .Range("B7").AutoFilter field:=17, Criteria1:="Rotten"
        'On Error Resume Next
        .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B10")
        '.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    With ws2.Range("B10:Y1400").Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    MsgBox ("Search done.")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

1. Replace `field:=17` with `field:=1`. Your range is a single column and hence field should be `1`.
2. Also replace the line `.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B10")`

with this

```
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0)

'~~> Checking if there is something that was filtered
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B10")
Else
    MsgBox "Nothing found"
End If
```

Now what happens?

3. `Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet`

Only `ws2` is being declared as `Worksheet`. `ws1` is getting declared as `Variant`. Change that to

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
```